# Spring Data Jpa: save an entity with @ManyToOne

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I m working with spring boot, i have these two classes

```
@Entity
@Table(name="products")
public class Product implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long idProduit;
 //other attributes..
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="idCategory")
private Category category;
```

and category class :

```
@Entity
public class Category implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long idcategory;
//attributes...
@OneToMany(mappedBy="category")
private Collection<Product> products;
```

i want to code a methode to save product

```
public long saveProduct(Product p, Long idCat)
```

Is there a method defined in JpaRepository which can do this or, should i add a service Layer and define my method like below or define it a custom method in Repository ?

```
public long saveProduct(Product p, Long idCat){
    Category c=getCategory(idCat);
    p.setCategory(c);
    em.persist(p);
    return p.getIdProduct();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add a service Layer and define a `transactional` method  in order to handle exceptions like `CategoryNotFoundException` (when `Category c=getCategory(idCat)` fires one) ,
`DataIntegrityViolationException`....

Building a solution without a `service` Layer isn't a good practice, since you will have to handle `transactions` and `propagations` manually and you will risk having `dirty reads`.